# Calling an Int from another Script that lives on a Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, prefab

I'm super new to c# and I'm making a 3D game in Unity. I have an int that I want to call upon in another script, but the original script that the int is in, lives on a prefab that isn't on my terrain.

Here is my first code that lives on the Prefab.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Radish : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioSource munchSound;
    public int foodCollisions = 0;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Cow"))
        {
            munchSound.Play();
            foodCollisions++;
        }
        
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

This is my second code that lives on a GameObject on my terrain.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class FriendMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Playerpos;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    private GameObject radishPrefab;
    private Radish radishScript;

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        radishPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Radish");
        GameObject radishInstance = Instantiate(radishPrefab);
        radishScript = radishInstance.GetComponent<Radish>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (radishScript.foodCollisions == 3)
        {
            agent.destination = Playerpos.position - new Vector3(5, 0, 5);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff but I keep getting errors on Unity :( please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see any relationship between these two  ... what is `Radish`? does it inherit from `Food`? What exact errors do you get?

Comment: @derHugo omg, my bad I just realized I uploaded the wrong script for the first portion. my bad, I haven't slept in a while. It's updated now and hopefully it makes more sense! Radish is the name of the GameObject that I turned into a Prefab. When I press the right mouse button, it shoots them out, like a gun but instead of bullets, it's vegetables. the error I was getting is that the reference is not set to an instance of an object, which it isn't since it's set to a prefab.

Comment: I think there is a good chance that on the object you load from resources there is no such component called `Radish` so `radishScript` stays null why not have a normal field `[SerializeField] private Radish radishPrefab;` instead of going through Resources at all (which is discouraged as per the [Best Practices](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) btw)... also `agent` or `Playerpos` could be null here so it is a bit hard to tell without seeing your exact error log message

Comment: @derHugo would it be alright to give you my discord so I can show you some pics about the error and how I have it set up? If so, it's yasmin rice#8081 and if not, that's totally fine! I completely understand :) just let me know and I'll try to continue explaining here. Thank you so much for your help by the way, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You may put the `Food` component on the new empty GameObject on your scene

Then add `public Food food` property into your `FriendMove`

Drag in the Inspector (Editor) your GameObject with Food into the field in FriendMove

After that you'll be able to reach the properties of Food object from the FriendMove